Projected Gradient Descent Applies on the Constraint $\boldsymbol{l} \leq \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{t} \leq \boldsymbol{u}$
I understand that in projected gradient descent, I need to project my (intermediate) solution to the feasible set with shortest distance like here:
What is the difference between projected gradient descent and ordinary gradient descent?
$$
\min_x f(x) \text{ subject to } x \in C
$$
$$
y_{k+1} = x_k - t_k \nabla f(x_k)\\
x_{k+1} = \text{arg} \min_{x \in C} \|y_{k+1}-x\| 
$$
So in my specific case, my optimization problem is $f(X) = \text{tr}(（I-X)A(I-X)^T + XBX^T )$ subject to $l \leq Xt \leq u$. $A, B$ are positive semidefinite matrices. $X$ is an $n$ by $m$ matrix, $l, u$ are known $n$ by $1$ vectors and $t$ is a known $m$ by $1$ vector.
How do I project a given $X$ to above feasible set?
Basically in the projection step I want to do something like $\min ||X - Y||^2$ s.t $Xt \leq b$, but this seems a bit  messy, as in I dont know how to exactly define $||X - Y||^2$ when $X, Y$ are matrices.
[EDIT]
If it's a problem with $x,y,a$ as vectors and $b$ as a scalar such as $\min_{x} || x - y ||^{2}$ subject to ${a}^{T} x \leq b$
Then I can find
$$ x = \begin{cases}
y & \text{ if } \; {a}^{T} y \leq b \\ 
y - \frac{{a}^{T} y - b}{ {\left\| a \right\|}_{2}^{2} } a & \text{ if } \; {a}^{T} y > b
\end{cases} $$

One way it to use a (convex) quadratic program.

The objective function does not yield a scalar. Probably you missed some reduction operator.

Why not just use a standard QP?

@copper.hat yes I can. I just want to study more how the projected GD works.

If you choose the Frobenius norm then the projection step just reduces to a standard QP in $\mathbb{R}^N$, for some $N$.

You may use the trick in Orthogonal Projection onto Half Space of Matrices.
It will generate the equivalent problem as:
$$ \boldsymbol{l} \leq \boldsymbol{T} \boldsymbol{x} \leq \boldsymbol{u} $$
Then you may reformulate it as:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} \phantom{-} \boldsymbol{T} \\ - \boldsymbol{T} \end{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x} \leq \begin{bmatrix} \phantom{-} \boldsymbol{u} \\ - \boldsymbol{l} \end{bmatrix} $$
Which is equivalent to the problem in Orthogonal Projection onto a Polyhedron (Matrix Inequality).

Thanks Royi, Can you see the edit to my problem body? I can solve a simpler vector case, but not a messy matrix case

@TaylorFang, If you look at the link I provided you'd see this is the sub problem to solve. See Orthogonal Projection onto a Half Space.

@TaylorFang, If you share the data / function, I would be able to show you in code.

yes, I see your link, but that's the vector/scalar case I can solve. I don't know how to solve the matrix case. My objective function is $(I-X)A(I-X)^{T} + X B X^T$ But I don't think it matters? It's just a matter of projecting to constraint feasible set, the objective function shouldn't matter?

@TaylorFang, I don't understand. Are you after $\boldsymbol{X}$ or $\boldsymbol{t}$?

@TaylorFang, Just write your problem completely. I will give a full solution.

I am after $X$, but $t$ is a known vector as a part of the constraint.  The constraint is $l \leq Xt \leq u$

I edited my question body. my optimization problem is $f(X) = （I-X)A(I-X)^T + XBX^T$ subject to $l \leq Xt \leq u$. $X$ is an $n$ by $m$ matrix, $l, u$ are known $n$ by $1$ vectors and $t$ is a known $m$ by $1$ vector. Thanks a lot for your help

@TaylorFang, The function you describe does not yield a scalar. Maybe you missed the Trace operator?

yes sorry there is a trace.  But if I understand correctly, the projected gradient descent method just cares about projecting to the constrained feasible set, not the obj function

@TaylorFang, I have updated the answer. You have a link to a trick you should employ I wrote for you.

beautiful, thank you
